# Existence of a first-order set theory corresponding to the first fully correct cardinal

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $\mathcal{L}$ denote the language of first-order set theory described in Chapter $1$ of “An introduction to set theory” [William A. R. Weiss | October 2, 2008].
Question: does there exist a consistent first-order set theory $T$ that satisfies both of the following two properties?

1. $T$ is infinitely axiomatizable and each axiom is formulated in $\mathcal{L}$ (assuming that the complexity of a formula is not restricted and every formula has a finite length);
2. There exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_{\alpha} \models T$; the smallest such ordinal is greater than or equal to the initial ordinal of the first *fully correct* cardinal.

[This answer on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71528) may be relevant, but I am unable to find a direct answer to my question.

Definition of the initial ordinal of a cardinal is given in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment) article.

The smallest fully correct cardinal is the cardinal $\Delta$ described in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/272900) answer on Mathoverflow.

Comment: I may be missing something, but can we not take $T$ to be the empty set? I assume you want some stronger properties than this.

Comment: @MarkSaving: what is "$T = \{\}$"? A first-order set theory with no axioms?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @MarkSaving: then what is the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_{\alpha} \models T$?

Comment: Could you say what you mean by a "fully correct" cardinal, and its "initial ordinal"?

Comment: @FarmerS: I added the relevant information to the edited question.

Comment: @MarkSaving I think the key clause in the OP is the post-semicolon part of the second buletpoint: "the smallest such ordinal is greater than or equal to the initial ordinal of the first fully correct cardinal." If we take the empty theory, we have $\min\{\alpha:V_\alpha\models\emptyset\}$ is either $0$ or $1$ depending on whether we allow the empty structure, which is much less than $\Delta$. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it boils down to the following:

> $(*)\quad$ Can there be an $\alpha>\Delta$, where $\Delta$ is$^1$ the supremum of the (parameter-freely, first-order) definable ordinals in $V$, such that $V_\alpha\not\equiv V_\beta$ for any $\beta<\alpha$?

The answer to $(*)$ is, in fact, **negative**. Say that an ordinal $\alpha$ is *fresh* iff $V_\alpha\not\equiv V_\beta$ for any $\beta<\alpha$. Freshness is definable, but this means that "the supremum of the fresh ordinals" is a definable ordinal, and hence less than $\Delta$.

Consequently, we have:

> For every $\alpha\ge\Delta$ there is some $\beta<\alpha$ with $V_\alpha\equiv V_\beta$.

---

$^1$Note that I'm assuming here that $\Delta$ in fact exists. While at first glance a pretty banal statement for "Platonic $V$," there is [some surprising nuance here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597); that said, in the context of this question I think it's worth largely taking for granted.

Comment: Suppose that $T$ is some theory described by an arbitrarily complex, infinite set of axioms. Then $\alpha$ is the smallest ordinal such that $V_{\alpha} \models T$ (i.e. $\alpha$ is fresh for $T$). Does this answer imply that, no matter what $T$ is chosen, there exists a _finite_ formula $\phi$ that defines an ordinal $\beta > \alpha$? I am wondering how it can be done... The complexity and length of $\phi$ must be fixed, while the set of axioms of $T$ may contain formulas of arbitrarily large complexity and length.

Comment: Basically, the subtlety that I want to clarify is that $\Delta$ is the supremum of ordinals that are definable by finite formulas (if my understanding of the definition of a correct cardinal is correct). Yet a particular $T$ is not necessarily describable by a finite formula.

Comment: @lyricallywicked Yes - the singe formula "The supremum of the fresh ordinals" defines an ordinal greater than all fresh ordinals.